# C/C++ compilation. Having trouble with simple makefile for a project

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I been working on this makefile for hours and it seems like no changes are working, but it seems totally fine to me. Maybe I am missing something fundamental?

### Here is how the directory looks:

```
project
    makefile
    \obj
         checkInput.cpp
         olend.cpp
    \include
         checkInput.h
```

### Here is makefile:

```
I_DIR = include
OBJ_DIR = obj
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -I$(I_DIR)

MAIN = olend
SRCS = checkInput.cpp

OBJ_SRCS = $(subst .cpp, .o, $(SRCS)), $(MAIN).o
OBJS = $(patsubst %, $(OBJ_DIR)/%, $(OBJ_SRCS))

DEP_SRCS = $(subst .cpp,.h,$(SRCS))
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(I_DIR)/%,$(DEP_SRCS))

all: $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(MAIN)
```

---

I'm looking to get an executable "olend", and the error I am currently getting is,

```
"No rule to make target 'obj/olend.o,', needed by `olend'.  Stop."
```

Which is very straight forward error, but I don't understand how that could be happening,
`$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o`
should include `obj/olend.o` as a target. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at the error message, it says that the target it can't find is **'obj/olend.o,'** - notice the extra comma at the end. This comes from the way you defined your `OBJ_SRCS` variable. It should look like this:

```
OBJ_SRCS = $(subst .cpp,.o, $(SRCS)) $(MAIN).o
```

Notice there is no space before `.o` (this caused it to generate filenames like `checkInput .o`) and there is no comma before the `$(MAIN)` part (this caused it to generate something like this: `checkInput.o, olend.o`).

Comment: Ionut, you're a legend! Thank you.

Comment: The space before `$(SRCS)` is also not necessary or "correct" (but doesn't hurt in the same way as the space before `.o` does).